# I attempted to repair a hard drive and it doesn't show up anymore

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure, hardware-detection

I have a computer who's motherboard fried, and in the beginning the hard drive was detected by the computer but I couldn't access the files so I tried using the program TestDisk to fix it. From the program itself I was able to see some files and I attempted to undelete some sectors but after that the HDD wouldn't show up in windows.

Any idea how I can fix it now? The drive sounds like it is spinning properly, no clicking noises, but TestDisk doesn't even detect it anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try it in another computer, either internally or mounted in a USB enclosure, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/UGREEN-External-Enclosure-Supported-Compatible/dp/B06XWRRMYX/ref=sr_1_3

Comment: I tried both to no avail. Shkoiach

Comment: You could use Ultimate Boot CD, and try replicate the drive to a new physical disk by using parted magic. Check the BIOS, or UEFI to make sure even the machine is detecting it. Good luck... chances are pretty low.

Comment: @warfy thanks I just downloaded the iso and will give it a try as soon as I have a chance!